# Strange thing happens in calling the function 'InetAddress.getAllByName()'

Tags: java, java-8, centos

- 1. There is a downloading thread in my java app and it downloads the file and also calls the function '**InetAddress.getAllByName()**'.
- 2. I start the app and then turn off the network. About 2 minutes later, I turn on the network. I always get an exception 'UnknownHostException'.
- 3. But if I add a new thread in my app and it always calls function '**InetAddress.getAllByName()**' in a loop.
- 4. Repeat the step 2, and all of them can successfully get the ip and host name.

**Environment: Centos 7, OpenJDK 1.8**

Comment: Could you please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question so we could test it for ourselves? This sounds a bit strange to be honest.

Comment: Seems to be some caching in the DNS subsys...

Comment: When I added the optional property  '-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun' in the running command line, this error is gone and a new error occurs.I get a exception 'lang.RuntimeException: bad nameserver configuration' when I change the network status time and again.